# Fancybox is opening at last clicked image

Tags: javascript, fancybox

I have fancybox installed and whenever I close it and open it it always starts at the last clicked image. How do I sort it so that when I click an image it opens that specific image.

```
function initLightbox() {
    var activeClass = 'active';
    var win = jQuery(window);

jQuery('.products-list, .images-holder').each(function() {
    var holder = jQuery(this);

    holder.find('a.lightbox-link, a[data-rel*="lightbox"]').each(function(i) {
        var link = jQuery(this);
        link.attr('rel', link.attr('data-rel')).fancybox({
            padding: 0,
            margin: 0,
            cyclic: false,
            autoScale: true,
            overlayShow: true,
            overlayOpacity: .7,
            overlayColor: '#000000',
            titlePosition: 'inside',
            speedIn:0,
            speedOut: 0,
            onComplete: function(box) {
                jQuery(window).unbind('resize.fb').unbind('scroll.fb');
                // jQuery(window).unbind("center.fb").unbind('center.fb');

                jQuery('#fancybox-wrap').css({
                    opacity: 0
                });

                if (link.attr('href').indexOf('#') === 0) {
                    jQuery('#fancybox-content').find('a.close').unbind('click.fb').bind('click.fb', function(e) {
                        jQuery.fancybox.close();
                        e.preventDefault();
                    });
                }
                slideShowModal(i, jQuery.fancybox, jQuery('#fancybox-wrap'));
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Here is my php code:

```
<li>
    <?php if($popup_image) echo '<a class="lightbox-link" href="#popup-' . $term->slug . '">' ?>
    <?php if( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
    <span class="img-holder"><?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail_220x220') ?></span>
        <?php endif ?>
    <?php the_title('<span class="text">', '</span>'); ?>
                            <?php if($popup_image) echo '</a>' ?>
                                    </li>
```

To be honest this was setup by someone else so I'm a bit unsure what happened with it.

Comment: Just take your fancybox script out of the `.each()` method

Comment: Ah right, thank you, I'll give it a go.